# Cannot execute binary file?

Tags: raspbian

Trying to run Sunvox on my RPi, gives the title error on . sunvox

```
file sunvox
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABIS version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armfh.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[shal]=96fcb93ee25d6ffc8530852d661bf806dfcb9ae4, not stripped

uname -a
Linux Asmodean_ 4.1.7-v7+ #817 SMP PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:32:00 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

`./sunvox` yields "Permission Denied" but `sudo ./sunvox` gives "command not found".

What do?

Comment: Edit in the output of `stat ./sunvox`; "permission denied" could simply mean it is not excecutable (`chmod a+x sunvox`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Permission denied` is what you get if the command doesn't have execute permission. You can add it with:

```
chmod +x sunvox
```

With Raspbian, most network or USB-attached filesystems don't allow execution for security reasons. Commands need to be on a local filesystem

Comment: Yes thank you! It was running on a flash drive. I'll move it over.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're also seeing "command not found" makes me wonder if it's more than a permission issue. It might refer to a missing linker, program interpreter or similar shared dependency - especially if you compiled the binary on a different system.

First of all, I suggest you fix the permissions by typing `sudo chmod +x sunvox`.
If that doesn't solve the issue, try showing the shared library dependencies by typing `ldd sunvox`. If some of the paths printed don't exist, you could either transfer the files from another machine or recompile the binary on your target platform.